# Javascript function adding checkboxes to a total number?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function where I'm trying to add the total number of checkboxes ticked to a value that is already displayed in the textbox. The solution I have works but it doesn't update properly if I uncheck the boxes and click total again.

Is there a way I can fix this so that the textbox updates accordingly?

HTML

```
<td><input type="text" name="Yeses" id="NumberofRisks" class = "form-control" value ="<?php echo $row['Total-Score'];?> " style = "width:50px"></td>
```

Javascript

```
function sum()
{
  sumField = document.getElementById("NumberofRisks");
   var sum = sumField.value;

    $("input[name^='yanswer']:checked").each(function(){
    sum++;        

    });

    sumField.value = sum;


}
```

Comment: for that you'll have to add onchange event listener on your checkbox..!

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the value of the input after every call to `function sum()`.

Instead have the initial `sum` value.

Then every time use this value.

```
var initial   = $("#NumberofRisks").val();

function sum()
{
     $("#NumberofRisks").val(initial + $("input[name^='yanswer']:checked").length);

     displayRating($("#NumberofRisks").val());
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying but when  I've tried this and when I total I get a NaN in the total box

Comment: I updated the original post, the display rating part did not need to be in there.

Comment: make sure the code is after input tag or to the end of body tag

Comment: It is, I took out the display rating function.

Comment: what that initial variable is holding, can you print and let me know

Comment: It holds a number from the previous page, for example say it could be 8. The checkboxes then add to the number that's in the box. At the moment it prints NaN when I click total.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the original value of the textbox in a variable. Add an event listener to the checkboxes that count the number of checked boxes and adds that number to the original value, then updates the textbox.

Something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
<input type="textbox" class="text" />
```

JS:

```
//Store the original value. The 5 here should be whatever was supposed to be in the textbox.
var originalValue = 5;
$('.text').val(originalValue);

$('.check').on('change', function() {
    //Count the number of checked boxes and add it to the original value for display.
    var checked = $('.check:checked').length;
    $('.text').val(originalValue+checked);
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hptsq9qd/).